# Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

```
Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.8

    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:417:in `validate_ruby!'
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:91:in `setup'
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'

bundler: failed to load command: rake (/home/deploy/.bundler/app_name/ruby/2.1.0/bin/rake)
```

All the places it is showing: 2.1.8

ruby -v ==>  2.1.8
Gemfile has ==> 2.1.8

No idea about where it is taking version 2.3.1 from.

I want to remove 2.3.1 from wherever it is taking it.

Not sure, its an error related to chef setup or ruby installation on server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post header of your Gemfile? it should contain line `ruby "2.1.8"`. You should change that value to `2.3.1`. But be careful because you may need some refactor in your app

Comment: all the places it is: 2.1.8. 
ruby -v => 2.1.8
Gemfile has => ruby 2.1.8

Comment: so `ruby -v` executed on server also shows 2.1.8? You can check also how your ruby is set on server by executing `which ruby`

Comment: yes, ruby -v executed on server also shows 2.1.8.
which ruby shows `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 1):

Your `bundle` executable apparently is linked to the Ruby shipped with your local Chef installation (which uses Ruby 2.3.1 in this case).

This can happen when chef's executables are in your `PATH` and you don't have a different version of bundler installed elsewhere.

Assuming that you have a sane `PATH`, it might be enough to run

```
gem install bundler
```

to install the current version of bundler with your own Ruby (that is, the one install in `/usr/local` rather than in `/opt/chef/embedded`).